# Add a new element in an existing object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert an new element in an already existed javaScript object.
What I've tried is this:

```
var newElement = someValue;

1/ obj.newElement = value
2/ obj[newElement] = value
3/ $(obj).extend({newElement: value})
```

But none of them is working?

What I want to do is

```
var tuple = {};
var f = ["a","b"...]; // there are many values in the array

tuple[f[0]] = "c";
tuple[f[1]] = "d";
```

I also tried jQuery

```
$(tuple).extend({f[0]:"c",f[1]:"d"});
```

Comment: the 1) and 2) work. are you sure obj exists ?

Comment: yeah actually it is like. var newElement;    And then i'm trying to insert this newElement as a key in object

Comment: So are you using jQuery and trying to add an element to the collection, the third option implies that?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I also tried jQuery but that's also not working

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Yes, Obj exists but the problem is that newElement I'm adding is itself a variable and I want it's value as key in my obj

Comment: It wasn't working because of m mistake, I declared the obj and array in the a block and trying to access it outside that block.

Answer (score 3):

The first attempt should work, and for the second you have to add quotes to `newElement` :

```
obj["newElement"] = value
```

Because without quotes the `newElement` will be considered as a variable and you will get the following error message :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: newElement is not defined

---

```js
var my_object= {test: 'test'};

my_object.newElement = 10;
//Or
my_object['newElement'] = 10;

console.log(my_object); //Object {test: "test", newElement: 10}
```

---

**After your update**

Now if you have `newElement` as variable, the first attempt will add attribute `newElement` and not the value you have inside `newElement` variable, and for the second it will work fine, check snippet bellow.

```js
var obj={test: 'test'};
var newElement = 'someValue';

obj.newElement = 10
//or
obj[newElement] = 10

console.log(obj); //{test: "test", newElement: 10, someValue: 10}
```